# How do you proc specific mega veggies in Veggie Samurai?

Tags: ios, veggie-samurai

I am a big fan of iPhone/iPad games [Fruit Ninja](http://www.fruitninja.com/) and [Veggie Samurai](http://www.veggiesamurai.com/), the latter being a clone of the former.  In the game, there is a concept of a "Mega-Veggie".  Essentially, normal veggies stop being thrown up, and one huge veggie comes out and you have to dice it many times to score a bunch of points.

In the current iteration of the game, there are three mega veggies I am aware of:

1) Mega Onion (Turns into Onion Blossom, +100 points)
2) Mega Carrot (Once diced grants +500 points)
3) Mega Pepper (Once diced grants +100 points)
4) Mega Potato (Once diced grants +100 points)

While I have certain intuitions about how to proc these mega veggies, there must be some underlying rules as to what makes them pop up.

What do you need to do to trigger each mega veggie type?

Comment: I just want to say that "Veggie Samurai: Proc the Mega Veggies" would be a great title for a musical album.

Comment: hahaha, I absolutely agree.  If you go ahead and record a studio album, I grant you all rights to use it as you please.

Comment: Still a few too many uncertainties to select an answer, will wait until someone has something more concrete about each.

Comment: The peas are mega veggies too. You have to get all 3 of the peas to get the points

Answer (score 4):

Onion - 4 Dice combo including an Onion.

Pepper - 4 Slice combo including a Pepper.

Potato - 2 Dice combo with 2 Potatoes.

Carrot - I am not sure on this one but I know it has something to do with very large dice combos prior to seeing it.  (30+)

Answer (score 3):

To get the mega pepper you have to cut at least 4 veggies in one slash with one of the veggies being a pepper.

There's also a mega potato, to get that you need to cut and dice 2 potatoes completely in one go.

The others I'm not sure how to get

Answer (score 3):

The minimum is not three 10 dice chains for the mega-carrot. I agree that it involves high dice chains, but I know I have gotten the carrot with only two 10-dice chains. I imagine it is more like the pepper or potato. You could potentially come to the conclusion that getting the mega pepper happens after getting 5 or more 4-slice combos, but that would be erroneous. It seems pretty well established that it simply requires one 4 slice combo that includes a pepper. But you might come to the conclusion that it takes 5 slice combos simply because not every combo does include a pepper. I think that the mega carrot really only requires one 10-dice chain (10 or more) that includes 2 or 3 or 4 carrots. That would seem more consistent with what is required to make the other Mega Veggies. Carrots do not seem to be the most common of veggies to pop up, and they are some of the easiest to lose your chain on because of their small pieces (the key to fame and glory on this game is a three-finger method. SOOO much easier to dice carrots and everything. Anyway...)

Well, that's my two-cents on the mega carrots. Speaking from my own experience, of all of the mega carrots I have gotten (probably a few dozen), I don't remember any round where I only got one 10-dice chain and got a carrot, but I have gotten two mega carrots in close time-proximity, which wouldn't have allowed for 2 or three chains in between.

Comment: Also, I'd like to know if anyone has any input on what makes the peas show up. I've seen them on harmony mode at like 5 veggies in. I've even seen them show up on harmony mode without doing anything. Are they totally random?

Comment: Hey Flink, if you have a separate question (about the peas) I recommend using the "ask question" button on the top-right to ask a new question about it. Not only is it the "proper" way to ask questions on this site, it is also more likely to be seen by other users :)

Answer (score 2):

Mega Pepper - 4 (or higher)x slice combo, including at least one pepper

Mega Onion - Dice 5 (?) onions in a row (not absolute row, but not let any onion undiced through the game)

Mega Potato - Multi-dice x 2 (or higher I suppose) including at least 2 potatoes.

Mega Carrot - It keeps appearing randomly after succeeding 3 (I think it worked for 2 also) 10-dice chain.

1st and 3rd are 100% percent accurate.
As for 2nd and 4th, it's really close but you'll need to try it out and see if it works out.

Last note is about mega carrot: Everytime i got 3 10-dice chains, it shows up. And if you fail to dice it, it'll show up again, sooner or later. I'm pretty sure it's appearance after that is random. Or depends to current score. Need more opinions here.

Comment: Welcome to the site ifrit. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion board, so what your post should be an answer to the original question, and not as a response to another answer - see the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information. In any case, if you want to add more information about mega veggies later, please write it here by *editing your existing answer* and not by adding a new answer. Good luck with finding out the data.

Comment: I'll edit it so it looks more like an answer to the original question rather than a conversation starter. Though, I still believe it's adding info on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to spot the MEGA EGGPLANT, you need to have three 20 dice chains and successfully cut a carrot. This is hard, but worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum for the mega carrot is this:

Any combination of at least 30-dice chains, for instance:

3 separate 10-dice chains
or one 20-dice chain, and then one-10 dice, or vice-versa
or 30-dice chain

Note that if you get, say, a 16-dice chain, then later get a 14-dice chain, that doesn't get you the carrots: it is only recorded as two 10-dice chains.

Then they start popping up randomly. However, even when they pop up, they're pretty hard to cut. I have yet to figure out the strategy for cutting them.

Comment: For strategies on how to cut them, use all your fingers!  Don't start cutting until it reaches the top of the trajectory, and pay special attention to the smaller end of the carrot as it has a lot of places it needs to be cut to get credit.